# VB.NET file filter

Tags: vb.net

[image]

I want get the oldest creation file in a directory but want to exclude the file ‘Startup’(Which is currently the oldest file). So I would like to skip that file and get the next oldest creation file in the directory which would be ‘TEST’.

This code only gets the Startup.

```
Dim oldestFile = folderlist.OrderBy(Function(fi) fi.CreationTime).First
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTM6V.png):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `Where` function to filter.

```vb
Dim folder As New DirectoryInfo(folderPath)
Dim oldestFile = folder.EnumerateFiles().
                        Where(Function(fi) fi.Name <> "Startup.txt").
                        OrderBy(Function(fi) fi.CreationTime).
                        First()
```

Note that it is preferable to use `EnumerateFiles` rather than `GetFiles` unless you really want access to the full array of files after the fact. If you only need that one file, `EnumerateFiles` is better because it doesn't get all the files first and then perform the other operations on that array. You may already know this but most people don't at first.

Note also that I'm assuming that those are text files based on the icons. Change the name in the filter if they are something else. As a developer, you really ought to switch off the File Explorer feature that hides file extensions. That's for people who don't understand computers.